# mvvmcross login viewmodel-viewcontroller communciation

Tags: xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I am using Mvvmcross crosscore in my project

I am trying to bind my loginviewmodel to the loginviewcontroller

I bound a command for the login button. the app waits until it gets a login response, which is stored in the loginViewModel itself..

How can I communicate this to the loginviewcontroller --- regarding the login status and login error message if any

Can I access the viewmodel datacontext inside my loginviewcontroller ??? and how ?

What is the best approach to communication any items in the viewmodel back ( I basically mean all the NON-UI binding items)

Comment: It would be easier to answer, this question if you posted some code showing what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

One of the best methods solving viewmodel interdependencies is using a loosely coupled approch using the MessageBus/Event Aggregator pattern. There's a [plugin for MvvmCross](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/MvvmCross-plugins#messenger). Or you could use the excellent [TinyMessenger](https://github.com/grumpydev/TinyMessenger).

In principle when using this approach, you no longer establish hard references between the publisher and consumers of arbitrary notifications. Instead notifications get published on a message bus and every one is free to listen and subscribe.

Answer (score 1):

> I am using Mvvmcross crosscore in my project

I'm assuming from this that you followed the CrossLight sample N=39.

> Can I access the viewmodel datacontext inside my loginviewcontroller ??? and how ?

If you followed N=39. then you can access the DataContext using the property called `DataContext` - see https://github.com/MvvmCross/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross/blob/master/N-39-CrossLight-Touch/CrossLightTouch/MyViewController.cs#L33

```
    public object DataContext
    {
        get { return BindingContext.DataContext; }
        set { BindingContext.DataContext = value; }
    }
```

Beyond this, there are many other examples in the N+1 videos which demonstrate how to communicate between ViewModels and Views including error messages and loading dialogs - e.g. N=34 shows one implementation of progress dialogs - https://github.com/MvvmCross/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross/tree/master/N-34-Progress

A complete index of N+1 videos is available on http://mvvmcross.wordpress.com

Obviously not all of these are appropriate for your CrossLight approach to development, but this is where you can allow your custom mvvm approach to fill the gap - it's code for you to write in your custom framework.